react-draggable parent boundaries are misaligned for other elements depending on one element
<PresentationBox ref={ref}>
          {elements.map((element, index) => {
            return displayElement(element, index);
          })}
...

I have a box with draggable elements inside.
// displayElement
      return (
        <Draggable key={index}
          bounds="parent"
          onStop={handleStop}
          nodeRef={nodeRef}
          position={{ x: boxWidth * (Number(element.left) / 100), y: boxHeight * (Number(element.top) / 100) }}
        >
          <div style={elementStyle}
            onContextMenu={handleClick}
            onClick={handleClick}
            ref={nodeRef}
          >
            {element.content}
          </div>
        </Draggable>
      );

These draggable elements are supposed to be bound by the parent container. However, whenever I add a new element, the previous elements behave as if they are uniformly the same size as the new element. This allows them to potentially clip outside of the parent container, or be bound further inside like the screenshot below.
Problem SS
Has anyone experienced anything similar? I'd be happy to provide more code snippets.
